# Eclipse / Android - how to monitor device's HTTP traffic

Tags: android, eclipse, http, device, monitor

I have my device connected to debug Android apps, but I need to see the HTTP requests and responses (inc. header info).

I've seen a similar question asked on how to do this for an emulator, but how to do this when a real device is connected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), is a really powerful tool that does exactly what you need.

Charles allows you to sniff the packets sent through HTTP from your actual device, the way you use it is simple:

- Download and install Charles, run the program and specify the proxy port
- Connect the Android Device to the very same network of the computer running Charles
- Go to Wifi-Settings in Android Device and long tap on the network connected, then go to Modify Network-> Show advanced Options
- Set Proxy as Manual and in Proxy Host name set your computer IP "192.xxx.x.x" and in the Proxy port add the same port specified in Charles Proxy Settings.

And that's it, all the traffic from your phone will be proxy to charles and it will show you headers, parameters, etc...

Hope it Helps

Regards!

Comment: Thanks, but I already have HttpTracer on my computer - the problem is getting the phone to use it as a proxy. (Presumably, I'd have the same problem with Charles?)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I have no wi-fi available though - my phone (and computer) connect via the phone's 3G connection...

Comment: I'm on a wi-fi connection now, and it's working great - many thanks.

Comment: To find the IP address of your computer, open up a Command Prompt window, type in "ipconfig" and hit enter, and use the IPv4 Address value.

Comment: @user1617737 if it was a helpful response, would be nice if you marked as correct for further readers to notice and for people to take time answering your questions... Regards!

Comment: If you are wanting to monitor HTTPS, you can set Charles up for this, plus you will also need to install the Charles CA certificate on your device by navigating to this URL on your device - http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt - and setting the "Credential use" to "Wi-Fi".