# How to monitor HTTP (get, post etc) requests that my app is making in android

Tags: android, http, remote-debugging

In my own app, I'm using various 3rd party SDKs that make network calls( HTTP requests) in some form or other. Without editing this code, can I write code separately within the application to intercept all GET and POST requests that my app is making?

I want to record these HTTP calls in my app

I am aware of using [Fiddler](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2014/06/sniffing-http-traffic-on-an-android-device.html) and [Charles proxy tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077533/eclipse-android-how-to-monitor-devices-http-traffic) but that is outside the app but this won't work because I can't record these HTTP calls in my app.

Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: I am using Google Analytics SDK and Facebook SDK in my code. I want to monitor all the network calls these SDK's are making from my app

Comment: You want to intercept the request or response ?

Comment: Post some details of your current test code or samples of what you have tried. Also, explain why you need to use 3rd party SDK's instead of the built in methods.

Comment: @Tigger - I am using Google Analytics SDK and Facebook SDK in my code. I want to monitor all the network calls these SDK's are making from my app, and possibly be able to log/edit the requests/responses.

Comment: @PedroLobito - Both requests and responses.

Comment: Force the respective 3rd party libs thru proxy as step 1

Comment: @atmaish, I'm facing a similar task. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On non rooted phone you can use android OS proxy and redirect traffic. But some apps doesn't respect it. Makes direct connections. Some tweaking could be done. Use Drony with VPN mode to redirect all traffic to SandroProxy. Here is video how capture then traffic with SandroProxy  [SandroProxy with Chrome devtools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtVXBqT2v2o) SandroProxy can also capture pcapfiles. Can also make ssl mitm on pcap flow. from SandroProxy support

Comment: The phone need to be rooted?

Comment: Please improve the English statement.

Answer (score 14):

Try [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/android/) - it's an open-source tool I've been building to do exactly this. It can automatically intercept traffic from an Android device, with no manual setup required, and then allows you to inspect & rewrite all HTTP traffic from your computer, like so:

[image: Screenshot of the tool with a phone alongside]

To intercept HTTPS traffic from your app, you just need to either a) trust 'user' certificates in your application's network security configuration (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38770284/68051) or b) use an emulator or rooted device (in which case HTTP Toolkit can inject a 'system' certificate, which your app will trust automatically).

Answer (score 3):

Charles proxy is a good way.

Others include if app is using singleton network class (which it ideally should), make one function for get and one for post. Call these functions from your classes and use log.d to output data on console. You can track request response or time taken.

Comment: Like i said, I cannot use Charles proxy as I need to make it from app.

Also, there can't be singleton class as these calls will be made by respective SDK's

Comment: Charles proxy is configurable to app

Comment: I agree, but what I need here is some version of Charles proxy (some sdk maybe?) that I can put in my app and ship. Possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically looking for your app to be capable of recording the HTTP calls.
[Android Snooper](https://github.com/jainsahab/AndroidSnooper) library can be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Stetho?

http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

You can monitor and modify all incoming and outgoing requests, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck/

it adds a new app that send notifications each time a network request is made, and you can see the details of the request.

https://github.com/facebook/stetho

it allows you to use the chrome dev tools to monitor your requests created from an android app. (among other cool features)

Answer (score 0):

If you root the device or running over debug (adb), then maybe this will help:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/analyzing-android-network-traffic--mobile-10663

Else I don't think its possible to do what you want to do. But you can monitor general network stuff like:

For all traffic stats see:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html (just pass in your apps user id)

For monitoring network status:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this as the better option. Remember to scroll down the app and check network intercept is on.
Link is here https://appetize.io/upload

Comment: Please provide more details in the body of the answer rather than rely on an external link, which could go stale.