# Has Android changed SSL configuration in API 24?

Tags: android, ssl

When my Android 23 project attempts to connect to my server via HTTPS, all is fine.

If I switch the target SDK to 24, I get the following error:

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:198)
     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:443)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:394)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:170)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:563)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:444)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 13 more
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Switching back to 23 and it works again.
Has something changed in 24 regarding the minimum requirements for certificates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User-installed certificates, via the Settings app, are not incorporated by default on Android 7.0 if your `targetSdkVersion` is 24+:

> By default secure (e.g. TLS, HTTPS) connections from all apps trust the pre-installed system CAs, and apps targeting API level 23 (Android M) and below also trust the user-added CA store by default.

(from [the network security configuration docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html#CustomTrust))

To work around that, you will need to define a [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html) XML resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then, point to that XML resource from your `android:networkSecurityConfig` attribute in your `<application>` element in your manifest.

---

In general, Android 7.0 routes HTTPS through the network security configuration subsystem (`android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager` and kin from your stack trace). It's possible that there are other compatibility issues introduced here that are tied to `targetSdkVersion`. So, if the lack of user certificates is not your issue, and you can create a sample project that reproduces the problem, [file an issue](http://b.android.com). Since I maintain [a backport of that stuff](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity), I would be interested in knowing about any bugs. :-)

Comment: Yes, I found that info as you published this. Indeed it seems my certificate is in the user-installed trust.

Comment: @NathanH: Your app can opt into using user-installed certificates via `<certificates src="user"/>`. If possible, though, do something else. User-installed certificates are device-wide, which isn't great. You should be able to set up a [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html) that bakes in the desired certificate into your app.

Comment: Where should I put this XML line you provided? I'm not too worried about the real security, this is for a test

Comment: @NathanH: That would go in an XML resource, where you provide a [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html). Something [like this](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html#TrustingAdditionalCas), but where you include `<certificates src="user"/>` and drop the `<certificates src="@raw/extracas"/>` (which you will not have) should work. Then, add `android:networkSecurityConfig` to `<application>`, pointing to that XML resource.

Comment: Works! Would you mind adding this workaround to your answer as well?

Comment: How should i found the value for trust-anchors

Comment: @abhijitcaps: Talk to the maintainers of the server. If you have additional concerns in this area, please consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide more details about what problems you are encountering.

Comment: Should any code be written for Andorid 7 to start using the "network security configuration subsystem" ?

Comment: @Andigor: Ideally, yes. In practice, that is question for your server maintainers. Deciding how to implement certificate pinning, for example, is their decision as much as it is a decision of the Android app developers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not so familiar with this topic. So the question is simple. I have a code which imports self signed certificate into the custom trust manager and then passes it to the SSLContext context. That stopped working on Android 7. I see there is new way of trusting to the certificates using XML configuration. So what should I pass now to the SSLContext if I am using that new scheme mentioned?

Comment: @Andigor: If you are configuring your self-signed certificate via network security configuration, you do not need an `SSLContext` at all. The network security configuration subsystem handles all of that for you. Just define the XML resource, add it to the manifest via `android:networkSecurityConfig`, and you are done.

Comment: note you may want to use `<debug-overrides>` rather than `<base-config>`