# Android X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted throws CertificateException on API > 23

Tags: android, security, ssl, x509

I'm trying to import a self-signed certificate to the trusted ones so the default browser accepts a connection to a website using it.

Using the code from https://github.com/bitfireAT/cadroid it comes down to a check via `X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted()` which works on API 23 but not on API 24/25 (set by `targetSdkVersion`).

```
public boolean isTrusted() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
    X509TrustManager tm = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];

    try {
        tm.checkServerTrusted(certificates, certificates[0].getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
        return true;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The certificate is successfully imported and trusted (verified by the browser / it shows up in system-settings > security > CA-certificates) so it should not throw the exception (and does not on API 23).

The only changes on Android 7.0 I've found are not mentioning any relating stuff (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#tls-ssl).

---

Any ideas, how to check if a certificate is trusted on API > 23?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/38770284/2170109 which resolves my problem.

> By default, secure connections (using protocols like TLS and HTTPS) from all apps trust the pre-installed system CAs, and apps targeting Android 6.0 (API level 23) and lower also trust the user-added CA store by default.

So I need to include a `networkSecurityConfig` in the manifest and allow user-certificates as well.